# How can you curl/fold the bottom corner of a UIView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview

I have a UIView with a coloured background and I use a curlup animation to change the background colour to give the effect of turning the page. This works and looks really good.
Whats letting it down is having an arrow button in the bottom corner that you press to turn the page.
Is it possible to actually fold the bottom corner over to show the colour of the page beneath and act as a button to fire the animation?

And if this is even possible, would it be able to be animated to curl/uncurl just this bottom corner?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a dynamic curl effet (with different size of curl when the user drag it for example), or just a static curl effet with the color beneath ?

Comment: I think a static curl effect would do. Just to make the 'page turn' button look better instead of just an arrow.

Comment: I thought about a png image representing a curling page, with transparency below to see a colored view beneath, but I think you want the curling image has the color of the current page, don't you ?

Comment: Yes. I'd thought of that also. There are 6 possible colours so worst case scenario would be 6 png's.

Comment: Actually it'd be 6  for each of the 4 resolutions so 24!

Comment: like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910588/animating-a-uiimageview-tint, you can tint your white curl image, so it would take the color of your choice !

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
YourViewController * myModalVC = [[YourViewController alloc] init];
[myModalVC setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl];
[myModalVC setDelegate:self];

[self presentModalViewController:myModalVC animated:YES];
[myModalVC release];
```

and if you want to make a custom animation of partial curl then [USE THIS](https://github.com/FairfaxMobile/FDCatalog)