# Is it possible to change UIImageView color while rotating image using CABasicAnimation?

Tags: objective-c, cabasicanimation

I am able to rotate the UIImageView with CABasicAnimation, but I was wondering if it's possible to change the color of the image as well while it rotates, so it transitions into that particular color?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. You can add multiple CA Animations to an object. You can also place them in a group and control the timing and other parameters as a group.

For example:

```
// make animation group
let myAnimations = CAAnimationGroup()
myAnimations.duration = 1
myAnimations.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

// make opacity animation
let opacity = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
opacity.fromValue = 0
opacity.toValue = 100

// make a bg color animation
let color = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "backgroundColor")
color.fromValue = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
color.toValue = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor

// make position animation
let position = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
position.fromValue = 0
position.toValue = contentView.center.y - 80

// add the animations to the group
myAnimations.animations = [opacity, position, color]

// add the group to the layer
myObject.layer.addAnimation(placeAnimation, forKey: "myAnimations")
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I did not know you could add multiple animations as an array.  I guess I should clarify with the color part, what would I do to change the color of the UIImageView?  I've tried applying a tint and setting the background color.

Comment: Are you trying to shift the color of the UIImage within the UIImageView?

Comment: Yeah, so it covers all the opaque parts of the image and not the transparent parts aka a dynamic mask.  I mean I guess the non-fully coding way would be to overlap the image with the mask of the color I already want but transition the opacity  from 0 to 1...

Comment: // image is a UIImage you're setting as your image for the UIImageView
    img = img.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)

    let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
    imageView.image = image

Sorry, apparently i can't format code in comments the way I wanted. http://prntscr.com/7pycyt thats what it looks like

Comment: That's what I wanted, but weirdly, setting the rendering mode myImg = [myImg imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate] causes nothing to be displayed..  The UIImageView's mode is Scale to Fill + drawing opaque.  I've set the image by name, and tested with the existing image that's already set with no go

Comment: Setting the tint, creates an orange block.

Comment: There's no keypath for tintColor it seems

Comment: @TimNuwin To be able to animate `UIImageView`'s tint color use `contentsMultiplyColor` as a `keyPath` for `CABasicAnimation`. Hers is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69568305/4850928)

(I know it's six years already, but somebody might still use it)