# How to add a CALayer to your view with a Blend mode?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a texture which I add as a separate layer for my viewcontroller view like below. The layer is not opaque. I want to set the blend mode for `textureLayer` to something like kCGBlendModeMultiply. How should I do it?

```
UIColor* textureBackground = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Texture.png"]];
CALayer* textureLayer = [[CALayer alloc] init];
[textureLayer setFrame:self.view.bounds];
[textureLayer setBackgroundColor:textureBackground.CGColor];
[textureLayer setOpacity:0.5];
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:textureLayer above:self.view.layer];
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410222/blending-modes-on-calayers-on-screen-is-that-possible